# Scrapy / Selenium - response url not being passed to web browser

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I am trying to scrap a site using Scrapy and Selenium.

I can get the web-browser to open using selenium but i am unable to get the start url into the web-browser.  At present, the web-browser opens, does nothing and then closes whilst i get the error "<405 https://etc etc>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed".

Which, as far as i understand, confirms that i am not being able to pass the url to the web-browser.

What am i doing wrong here?

```
import scrapy
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from glassdoor.items import GlassdoorItem


class glassdoorSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "glassdoor"
    allowed_domains = ["glassdoor.co.uk"]

    start_urls = ["https://www.glassdoor.co.uk/Overview/Working-at-Greene-King-EI_IE10160.11,22.htm",
    ]

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/andrew/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        time.sleep(5)


        for sel in response.xpath('//*[@id="EmpStats"]'):
            item = GlassdoorItem()
            item['rating'] = sel.xpath('//*[@class="notranslate ratingNum"]/text()').extract()
#            item['recommend'] = sel.xpath('//*[@class="address"]/text()').extract()
#            item['approval'] = sel.xpath('//*[@class="address"]/text()').extract()
            yield item

#        self.driver.close()
```

the logs I get from the above are:

```
2017-01-26 21:49:02 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.5 started (bot: glassdoor)
2017-01-26 21:49:02 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2017-01-26 21:49:02 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'glassdoor.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['glassdoor.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'glassdoor'}
2017-01-26 21:49:02 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
2017-01-26 21:49:04 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: POST http://127.0.0.1:58378/session {"requiredCapabilities": {}, "desiredCapabilities": {"platform": "ANY", "browserName": "chrome", "version": "", "chromeOptions": {"args": [], "extensions": []}, "javascriptEnabled": true}}
2017-01-26 21:49:06 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2017-01-26 21:49:06 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2017-01-26 21:49:06 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2017-01-26 21:49:06 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
2017-01-26 21:49:06 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2017-01-26 21:49:06 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-01-26 21:49:06 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2017-01-26 21:49:07 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (405) <GET https://www.glassdoor.co.uk/Overview/Working-at-Greene-King-EI_IE10160.11,22.htm> (referer: None)
2017-01-26 21:49:07 [scrapy] DEBUG: Ignoring response <405 https://www.glassdoor.co.uk/Overview/Working-at-Greene-King-EI_IE10160.11,22.htm>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2017-01-26 21:49:07 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-01-26 21:49:07 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 269,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 7412,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/405': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 26, 21, 49, 7, 388000),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 5,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 26, 21, 49, 6, 572000)}
2017-01-26 21:49:07 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: and what is the value of `response.url` you pass into `parse()`?

Comment: @Andersson i was hoping it would be the first url in the start_urls list which is "https://www.glassdoor.co.uk/Overview/Working-at-Greene-King-EI_IE10160.11,22.htm"

Comment: Why it should be so? :) Is there a line where you call `parse()` with this argument?

Comment: I believe that is within the Scrapy module?

Comment: Can you share your logs? As far as I can see, setting `self.driver` would not ask Scrapy to delegate fetching the response to Selenium. And inside `parse(self, response):`, `response` would still be the response from Scrapy's downloader. `self.driver.get(response.url)` and `for sel in response.xpath` are very distinct. The former will not update `response`.

Comment: logs added - I can see what the two users above are saying.  I have been working the code to see if I can get Scrapy to operate entirely off the web browser created by selenium - so far, no success.  I suspect I may need to find another way around this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, as suggest by both the replies, i was not passing the correct response to selenium.

Hence, by adding the line:

```
response1 = TextResponse(url=response.url, body=self.driver.page_source, encoding='utf-8')
```

and therefore changing one line of the code as well:

```
for sel in response1.xpath('//*[@id="EmpStats"]'):
```

the new code is (which works):

```
import scrapy
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from glassdoor.items import GlassdoorItem


class glassdoorSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    header = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0"}
    name = "glassdoor"
    allowed_domains = ["glassdoor.co.uk"]

    start_urls = ["https://www.glassdoor.co.uk/Overview/Working-at-Greene-King-EI_IE10160.11,22.htm",
    ]

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/andrew/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        response1 = TextResponse(url=response.url, body=self.driver.page_source, encoding='utf-8')
        time.sleep(5)


        for sel in response1.xpath('//*[@id="EmpStats"]'):
            item = GlassdoorItem()
            item['rating'] = sel.xpath('//*[@class="notranslate ratingNum"]/text()').extract()
#            item['recommend'] = sel.xpath('//*[@class="address"]/text()').extract()
#            item['approval'] = sel.xpath('//*[@class="address"]/text()').extract()
            yield item

#        self.driver.close()
```